# Laravel Modal Form Redirect Back With Input Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a button that when a user clicks on it a modal shows up with all the items passed in with the data attribute. Inside the modal theres a save button which gets passed to my controller. A validation runs and succeeds although I cant get the inputs to show again. I do get a red box to appear from the error.

When I try to use `{{ old('title') }}` nothing shows up.

```
<button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" data-toggle="modal" :data-id="link.id" :data-title="link.title" :data-link="link.link" :data-description="link.description" :data-enabled="link.enabled" data-target="#editLinkModal"></button>
```

Javascript:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    $('#editLinkModal').modal('show');
@endif



$('#editLinkModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){

var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
var title = $(e.relatedTarget).data('title');
var link = $(e.relatedTarget).data('link');
var description = $(e.relatedTarget).data('description')
var enabled = $(e.relatedTarget).data('enabled')


var body = $('.modal-content .modal-body');

$('.modal-title').text('Editing ' + title);

body.find('.title').val( title );
body.find('.link').val( link );
body.find('.description').val( description );
body.find('.enabled').val( enabled );

body.find('#editForm').attr('action', "/profile/updateLink/" + id);



$('.save').on('click', function(e){
    $('#editForm').submit();
    //updateLink(id);
});


});
```

Controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'title' => 'nullable|max:191',
      'link' => 'required|max:1000',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return back()
                ->withInput($request->all())
                ->withErrors($validator);

    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that handles the display of errors in the modal?

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily increasing the lines of code,

**Try changing this:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'title' => 'nullable|max:191',
      'link' => 'required|max:1000',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return back()
                ->withInput($request->all())
                ->withErrors($validator);

    }
```

**To:**

```
$request->validate( [
      'title' => 'nullable|max:191',
      'link' => 'required|max:1000',
    ]);
```

Calling the `validate()` method on the `$request` object will validate the request against the rules and automatically return back with errors if the validation fails.